# Associate files type with my Iphone App

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, file-type

I'm trying to associate files type with my application (pdf and doc).
For pdf, it's Ok. I read this subject: [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application)

and it works perfectly. But I tried to add the .doc type but it doesn't works.

**EDIT: It works with this code (PDF, WORD and EXCEL):**

Here is my app-info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon.png</string>
            <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My Apps Files</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.composite-content</string>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.content</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>PDF Document</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.composite-content</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>pdf</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/pdf</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Word Document</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>doc</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/msword</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.microsoft.excel.xls</string>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>Excel Document</string>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>xls</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/vnd.ms-excel</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Best regards,

Comment: You should use `UTImportedTypeDeclarations` instead since you're not the owner of those types. Refer to Microsoft Word's `Info.plist` contents for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is code for Doc file formate but it may not work for images.

```
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>Microsoft Word</string>
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>
<string>Alternate</string>
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
<array>
<string>com.microsoft.word.doc</string>
            <string>com.microsoft.word.wordml</string>
            <string>org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```